# Convert activity to service (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, service, android-activity

I'm developing an application that is meant to get information about the users location and the current weather. The information is gathered in this way: 
StartGathering --> Get lat/long --> Get location data (city, address etc) from coords --> Get weather info --> Save information in SQL database. 
Everything is done by sending a string array using bundle between the different activities containing the data.
For this to be accurate the process is repeated every X minute, but since I've worked with activities the updating process interferes with other applications on the device. I've added android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" for each of the activity in the process, thinking this would be the same as doing it in the background.
I want the information to be gathered and saved in the database in the background, and as far as I know this isn't possible without using services.

Is there a way to easily convert a bunch of different activities to services, and thus allowing the app to gather the necessary information in the background so that the user can use the device without any performance loss? 
Or is it possible for activities to do some work in the background without interfering with other applications?

Comment: I have no idea how literally do it. but I would like to try start a async task and make a loop after that finish the main intent. I dont know if it works but I just give it a shot :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to easily convert a bunch of different activities to services...

No, create a `Service` (or `Services`) and copy/paste your existing code in. Be aware though that a `Service` runs on the application's main thread (aka UI thread) so if there is any time-consuming work to be done you'll need to use worker threads or perhaps use `IntentService` which does it's work by default on a background/worker thread.

> Or is it possible for activities to do some work in the background without interfering with other applications?

No, not in the way you're attempting to do it. Think of an `Activity` as being analogous to a Windows Form (or similar). In other words  it is a framework for a UI allowing the user to interact with the app. There are ways of doing background work in an `Activity` (using `AsyncTask` for example) but an `Activity` isn't a generic class which can be hidden away whilst it does some 'number crunching'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Can I still use the same methods and send/receive bundles when working with services? And can I still program in the same way, that one service do some work and before it destroy itself it sends a bundle to another service that do some other work with the information from the previous one?

Comment: @Eric : Yes, a `Service` can start or bind to another `Service`. As for passing data, Android uses `Intents` extensively for communicating actions and passing data between different components of an app. I wonder if you really need more than one `Service` though. If the 'gathering' process of your app is always meant to be  done with the fixed steps you describe then why not do it within just one `Service`? The only reason to have multiple `Services` is if each one performs a unique function which may be of direct use to other app components.

Answer (score 2):

> thus allowing the app to gather the necessary information in the background so that the user can use the device without any performance loss

If your program is doing *anything* then you are causing "performance loss", perhaps not significant or noticable(to the user), but loss nonetheless. It seems to me that what you are trying to do (get location and make a web request to get weather info related to location every X minutes) is going to cause pretty significant drain on the battery depending on what interval time you are using. I suggest you leave the interval time up to your users if you do not want them to complain about your app draining their battery.

Comment: What I meant was "without any significant performance loss". When I tested the app on my phone and it gathered the information with activities it was basically impossible to use it at the same time. 
Of course the user will be able to configure how often it will gather information.